# Return a partial view from a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

So, we can return a partial view from a controller like this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using MvcApplication1.Models;

namespace MvcApplication1.Controllers
{
    public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Modify this template to jump-start your ASP.NET MVC application.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult About()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your app description page.";

            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult Contact()
        {
            ViewBag.Message = "Your contact page.";

            return View();
        }

        public PartialViewResult Address()
        {
            Address a = new Address 
            { 
                Line1 = "111 First Ave N.", 
                Line2 = "APT 222", 
                City = "Miami", 
                State = "FL", 
                Zip = "33133" 
            };

            return PartialView(@"~/Views/Home/_Address.cshtml", a);
        }
    }
}
```

But, how am I supposed to use the returned partial view?  I created _Address.cshtml under Views/Home, like this:

```
@model MvcApplication1.Models.Address

<p>
    This is a partial view of address.
</p>
<p>
  @Model.City
</p>
```

And, at the end of Views/Home/Contact.cshtml, I added this line:

```
@Html.Partial(@"~/Views/Home/_Address.cshtml")
```

And I expect to see the City of my address, but it doesn't show up. I am confused.

Comment: Thank you for formatting my code. I tried hard formatting it, but it refuses to format like I wanted.

Comment: It's actually pretty easy. Just select your code text, then hit the `{}` button in the editor OR make sure that all of it is indented 4 spaces.  You can also surround inline code with backticks `\`code\``

Comment: OK, thanks. Will try next time.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

When the partial takes a different model than the method you're including it in you need to use the overload that takes a model parameter and supply the model for the view. By default it uses the same model as the including view.  Typically you only need the path if it's in a different, non-shared folder.  If it's in the same controller's folder, using just the name should do the trick.

```
@Html.Partial("_Address", Model.Address)
```

On the other hand, if you're asking how do I get the partial view from an action included in my page, then you want to use the `Action` method instead of the `Partial` method.

```
@Html.Action("Address")
```

**EDIT**

To make the partial work you need to pass a `Contact` model to the contact view.

```
public ActionResult Contact()
{
     var contact = new Contact
     {
        Address = new Address
                  { 
                       Line1 = "111 First Ave N.",
                       Line2 = "APT 222",
                       City = "Miami",
                       State = "FL",
                       Zip = "33133"
                  }
     }

     return View(contact);
}
```

Comment: @Stack0verflow - that's because you're not passing a `Contact` model to the parent page.

Comment: But I am passing the @model MvcApplication1.Models.Address to my _Address.cshtml partial view.

Comment: But then you have taken my partial view action method out of the equation.

Comment: @Stack0verflow - that's where the second option, rendering an action in a view comes in.  That's the option you want to use if you want to include the result (partial view) of a different action.

Comment: Ah, that's how we use a partial view returned from an action method. Thanks a lot. Yes, the 2nd option works: @Html.Action("Address")

Comment: By the way, the information you give is very very helpful. Do a google search, you will be surprised that there is so little info about how exactly we use a partial view returned from a controller action method. Note: this is not about how to use a (static) partial view per se.

Answer (score 6):

demo for you:

```
    public ActionResult Update(Demo model)
{
    var item = db.Items.Where(item => item.Number == model.Number).First();
    if (item.Type=="EXPENSIVE")
    {
        return PartialView("name Partial", someViewModel);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, suppose my partial view name is _Address.cshtml, how am I supposed to use this partial view in my Contact.cshtml view?

Comment: if you can call partial in view, you can using : @{
    Html.RenderPartial("_Test");
}